# App Update without needing PlayStore like Facebook

Tags: android, react-native, google-play

Apps that under Facebook can do update automatically without needing PlayStore.
As I recall this is against PlayStore policy to do, so why this is still exist then?
Is this feature has something to do with the React framework?

I also read some post on Reddit [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/6aycy1/facebook_and_instagram_are_updating_themselves/) and [blog](https://blog.vivekpanyam.com/evolve-seamlessly-deploy-android-apps-to-users/?hn) that says apps that are distributed in PlayStore is not allowed to do update without the store mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

You must go through codepush it works for react native app https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://microsoft.github.io/code-push/&ved=2ahUKEwir06-2gqPnAhVMILcAHQHbCvAQFjAAegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw3EJjBJCEht7W9iQU5in_Uk

Answer (score 1):

check Android Native lib in-app Update app update without playstore

https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates